# pdf js not loading properly in HTML page

Tags: pdf.js

i had used pdf.js in one of my projects. It is loading in the example. But, In an HTML page, It shows loading. If i try to see in full screen, it loads the pdf and then shows the pdf in html page for about 10 seconds after exiting full screen view. After that it will shows blank page with loading.
Whenever I try to see the pdf in full screen the same happens.

If anyone got the solution or any idea why it is so, then please do reply ASAP.Thanks in advance

Comment: The one who gave a negative has to tell the reason.